# Macro for data extraction from one ws to another in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and looking to write an easy macro to extract data from one worksheet and add it to another worksheet, within the same workbook. Could any of you help me with a macro for the same? thanks!

Comment: I don't have anything, this is my first VBA code. Haven't done vba  ever before.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub copy
thisworkbook.sheets(put here number of sheet to copy TO).cells(rows,columns).value=thisworkbook.sheets(number of sheet to copy FROM).cells(rows,columns).value
end sub
```

example

```
Sub Copy()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(1,1).Value
End Sub
```

this one would copy contents from second sheet - cell "A1" to first sheet - cell "A1"

anything else?

Comment: to copy bigger areas instead of cells use range(cells(1,1),cells(3,1)) this one would copy contents from cells A1 to A3

Answer (score 0):

Since you have never coded before, you may want to add

```
Option Explicit
```

To the beginning of your code, above the

```
Sub Copy()
```

This is a more proper way of coding.

I remember starting my coding in vba and going through copying cells from one sheet to another. I suggest you start looking at For-Next statements as it will help when you begin to copy lots of data for example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Copy()
Dim intCounter as Integer     'intCounter is the variable when is denoted by a prefix 'int' and is a counter for the for statement
For intCounter=1 to Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows
'The above line denotes For the Counter = to 1 all the way to the end of the sheet
Sheets(1).Cells(intCounter,1).Value=Sheets(2).Cells(intCounter,1).Value
'The above will take the cell in Sheet 1 row intCounter Column 1 to Sheet 2 row intCounter Column 1
Next
'The Above line 'Next' will start the loop over, adding 1 to the Value of intCounter
End Sub
```

I suggest you play around with the code and see what changing values will do to the sub routine.

Also note, that the above sub routine is dependent on having data in Sheet1 and column 1 , and is only transferring data from 1 cell at a time, if you want to do more than one cell at a time, as mentioned above you can use

```
Range(Cells(intCounter,1),Cells(intCounter,whateverColumnNumberYouWant)).Value
```

in Place of

```
Cells(intCounter,1).Value
```

Hopefully, this gives you something to play with that will help your endeavors